# xdebug php 5.4 windows

Tags: php, windows, xdebug

Is there a compiled version of xdebug for PHP 5.4.0 (VC9 x86 Non Thread Safe) available for download anywhere?

I have had a look around but could only find 5.3 versions, or self compiling instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new [RC for 2.2.0](http://www.xdebug.org/download.php) has Windows binaries for 5.4